# Create Hyper-V from existing VHDX

Tags: hyper-v

We have some hyper-v server images that if possible we would like to not rebuild. However the original machine they were installed on is no longer available.

So we have 1 vhdx and 8 avhdx. The vhdx is the virtual disk and the avhdx are check points if I remember correctly.

The process I used to build these machines was such as base install...checkpoint..install SQL Server...checkpoint...install visual studio...checkpoint etc...

I created a new vm on my windows 8 box and in the create wizard I told it to use an existing vhdx then pointed to my previous one.

The system boots and takes the correct password. However it comes up at the base install point. The checkpoints do not show in Hyper-V manager and consequently they do not get applied to the VM.

Now I have found that there is a sort of checkpoint database (xml) and several related folders in

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V

thinking maybe there are some pointers I could realign but it seems editing them is not supported.

I also tried under the settings option of the test vm to change the checkpoint location. That seems to be a place for checkpoints to be stored and it doesn't seem to pick them up if any exist........this behavior makes sense as the pointer xml / database thingy is where that information should come from.

So is there a way to get these checkpoints associated / recreate / make use of these existing hyper v machines?

Thank You

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be the correct SO forum for this question.

Comment: Super User huh? Not sure I agree. The question isn't directly related to programming so I can see you point (these are dev virtual machines and my default SO forum is this one) but wouldn't perhaps a sys admin forum be better? Anyway your point is valid. I'll check for a better forum to post in.

Comment: My guess is you selected the VHDX file and not the AVHDX file. The VM should boot from the AVHDX file for the checkpoint(s) to be picked up by the VM.